# How to assign values in new column based on condition in another column using if and non-if functions in R

Tags: r, if-statement, variable-assignment

I have a data set "data". If the variable (in long form) contains A1 or D1, assign "1:5 dil" in data$dilutions column. If it has B1 or C1 assign "1:10 dil". 
How can I do this using both if and non-if functions?

In the original data I have lots of assignments, hence I want to see if non-if conditions work better

```
cycles <- c(1:100)
A1 <- c(1:100)
B1 <- c(100:199)
C1 <- c(5:104)
D1 <- c(0:99)
data <- data.frame("cycles" = cycles, "A1" = A1, "B1" = B1, "C1" = C1, "D1" = D1)


library(reshape2)
data <- melt(data, id.vars=c("cycles"))
data$dilutions <- if(data$variable=="A1"|"D1" <- "1:5 dil", data$variable== "B1" | "C1" <- "1:10 dil")
```

Comment: Surely this has been asked and answered before. If you have searched already, then you should include the search strategies that are not successful. (for one thing your use of `if` is incorrect, but that too is a question that has multiple prior ansers on SO and  the web..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your use of the `if` statement is incorrect. Here are two approaches, one making use of `ifelse()` and one using direct assignments on subsets.

```
data$dilutions <- ifelse(data$variable == "A1" | data$variable == "D1", "1:5 dil", "1:10 dil")
```

If you have more than these two possible outcomes, you may need to chain your `ifelse` statements (i.e., use another `ifelse()` for the `else` part of the call.

Otherwise, you can use direct assignments, like so:

```
data$dilutions[data$variable=="A1" | data$variable== "D1"] <- "1:5 dil"
data$dilutions[data$variable=="B1" | data$variable== "C1"] <- "1:10 dil"
```